# find multiple ids but order not respected from the initial array list with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a Favorite Model linked to my User Model. His relation is done with HasMany.
So i can retrieve all the Favorites from any user like this.

```
[User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 60
        [username] => username
        [email] => xxxxxx@gmail.com
    )
[Favorite] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [book_id] => 15
                [user_id] => 60
                [position] => 1
                [created] => 2012-08-08 04:08:54
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [book_id] => 17
                [user_id] => 60
                [position] => 1
                [created] => 2012-07-26 04:08:32
            )

    )
```

But this Result doesnt show me all the Book data and related objects. so i i decided to find them with a find('all') giving the list of ids ([15,16 ....]). The only problem is that its not linked to my order on Favorite.created DESC.
It retrieve me the Books Items in another order.

my query actually, look like:

```
    $result = $this->User->findById($id);
    $conditions = array('Book.id' => Set::extract($result, 'Favorite.{n}.book_id'));
    $favorites = $this->Book->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Any idea how i can change my model relation? or my query in cakephp?

Comment: Posting your current query would be a good start ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Join between your Book Model and your Favorite Model. In your case you can use BindModel to create the Join. Here in my example, i used 'hasOne' cause Cakephp doesnt make Joins with hasMany, only with hasOne and BelongsTo.

```
    $this->Book->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array(
                                    'Favorite' => array(
                                        'className' => 'Favorite'))));
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $data = $this->Book->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Favorite.user_id' => $id),
            'order' => array('Favorite.created' => 'DESC')));
```

That's all.

Comment: What I understood is "There should be HABTM relationship between Book and Favorite Model class. Not hasOne." What you suggest?

Comment: In this case Book have only one favorite from a specific user.

Comment: IF i use HABTM i dont have all the data i need to show. This solution serves me. thanks